# .apk file is not downloaded with codeigniter ('download') helper

Tags: file, codeigniter, download

I am working on codeigniter project . in that project i made a webview app (.apk). i upload the a.apk file in upload folder of the project but i am unable to get the .apk when i click on download button . my code is

```
public function downloadapp()
{

    $this->load->helper('download');
    $data = file_get_contents(base_url()."uploads/apk/hc.apk");
    $name = 'hc.apk';

    force_download($name, $data);
}
```

when i add some other file like(.jpg , .png ) then the doenload code is working fine .. but only .apk file is not downloaded .
please help me . and thanks in advance :)

Comment: use `FCPATH` instead of `base_url`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$file = base_url()."uploads/apk/hc.apk"; //not public folder

if( file_exists($file)){
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);

    exit;
}
```